# Django signals: conflicts with models inheritining from the same class

Tags: django, orm, signals, fixtures

I encountered a strange behavior while applying a **signal** to a new model, I'm not sure to understand what is wrong but it seems related with the fact that I used **abstract classes**.

## The models (simplified)

Basically, I have **Article**, **Photo** (inheriting from **Post**)

```
class Post(models.Model): 
    class Meta:
        abstract        = True

    some_field    = models.Something()

class Article(Post):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Article_category, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    some_field     = models.Something()

class Photo(Post):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Photo_category, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    some_field     = models.Something()
```

and their respective Categories

```
class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta: 
        abstract = True 

    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='nested_category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    count  = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
    
class Article_category(Category):

    @classmethod
    def load(cls):
        cache.set('{}'.format(cls.__name__), cls.objects.all()) 

class Photo_category(Category):

    @classmethod
    def load(cls):
        cache.set('{}'.format(cls.__name__), cls.objects.all())
```

## The signal

A straighforward incremental counter. Every time an article/photo is created, it's corresponding category count is updated and the entire model is saved in the cache (for templating purposes)

```
from django.db.models import F

@receiver(post_save, sender=Article) ----> here comes trouble
@receiver(post_save, sender=Photo)
def add_one_to_count(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    cat = type(instance.category).objects.get(name=instance.category)
    cat.count = F('count')+1
    cat.save()
    cache.set('{}_category'.format(sender.__name__), type(instance.category).objects.all())
```

## The problem

What you saw above works like a charm for `@receiver(post_save, sender=Photo)` but when I add `@receiver(post_save, sender=Article)`, DB initialization with *fixture* fails and I only get emptyset tables (**mariaDB**). This very line is the only one changing fail to success and I can't figure why. Since **count** is defined in the abstract class, I wondered whether it had something to do with it, for I did not have any issue applying a similar logic to categories:

```
# this works perfectly
@receiver(post_save, sender=Photo_category)
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Photo_category)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Article_category)
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Article_category)
def refresh_cached_category(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    cache.set('{}'.format(type(instance).__name__), type(instance).objects.all())
```

Thanks for any enlightenment

## The complete Traceback

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
     main()
   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
     utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 72, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 114, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 181, in load_label
    obj.save(using=self.using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 223, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 790, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/usr/src/cms/website/observers.py", line 26, in add_one_to_count
    cat = type(instance.category).objects.get(name=instance.category)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 408, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
 website.models.DoesNotExist: Problem installing fixture '/usr/src/cms/../test/data_dev.yaml': Article_category matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter on `name=instance.category` in your query, because that's not a `str`. You need to filter on `name=instance.category.name` but first you also need to make sure `instance.category` isn't `None` (since it can be).

The thing I don't understand is why you perform a query in the first place, just to fetch the same object: `instance.category` is the same as `ArticleCategory.objects.get(name=instance.category.name)` assuming the name is unique, except you do an extra query to the db.

Also the query will raise an exception if you have two categories with the same `name` (which you don't exclude in your model). So your code should be:

```
def add_one_to_count(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.category:
        instance.category.count = F('count')+1
        instance.category.save()
        cache.set('{}_category'.format(sender.__name__), type(instance.category).objects.all())
```

Comment: You're right, I was pretty circular. Your answer works. I guess what I experienced had to do with this extra-query on similar models